# Github for windows desktop does not recognize local repositiories anymore

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am using Github, the Windows desktop application. I had 5-6 local repositories, they all worked fine. Now, no repository shows up in the app anymore. My repositories do show up on github.com . In the desktop app, the app suggests I start by creating a new repository, exactly as it does after a fresh installation.

Any idea what is going on? I don't remember doing anything unusual before this happened.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,
Serban

Comment: Do each of them include a folder called `.git`?

Comment: Yes, they do. All of them.